# Which pie menus addon to use?

Tags: add-on, pie-menu

I want to use the pie menus addon, but confusingly I have two of them. The second is called "official", and it has a higher version number, but the first one seems to have a lot more hotkeys.

[image]

**EDIT** As I got here only generic answers, I researched and compared them, and here is what I found: the "unofficial" 3d Viewport Pie Menus are a new addon in 2.78, and as of 2.78 they seem to be more powerful than the official ones.

- Tab: the "unofficial" is better, because it has an Edit/Object toggle, and most of the time this is what we want. One can also directly jump to the edge/face/vertex selection sub-modes from the Object mode.
- Ctrl-Space: the "unofficial" is better, because it has combined widget options
- . (pivot setting): the same
- Z (shading): the same
- Ctrl-Shift-Tab (snap): the the "unofficial" seems more powerful
- q (views): the "unofficial" is definitely more powerful, it has not only the views, but options like lock camera to view.
- Clip Editor pies: this is only in the official
- There are 11 more pie menus only in the "unofficial", all of them can be activated individually, and as the accepted answer says, one can also combine them

More information about the "unofficial": https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?401789-3d-View-Pie-Menus

Comment: I think you should add your edit as an aswer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why you cannot use both and switch off/on functions that are suited to your workflow. I would recommend starting with the official and get to understand possible conflicts. An example of this is the <kbd>TAB</kbd> which access switching between 8 modes, where as before it was just between Edit and Object. Recently they added a new feature with micro-displacement where you can refresh the viewport render by hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> - which doesn't seem to work with the pie menu activated. One has to make choices.

I have the second pie menu activated, but with only one key - the <kbd>W</kbd> key  for the Sculpt menu. I find the rest cause confusion/ conflicts with other hotkeys I used. Having the choice to customize means you do indeed have to see what works for you. If you find stuff getting in the way - just un-tick those keys.

Comment: Thank you, but in this case there is a reason: the pie menus are not different, the "unofficial" version contains the "official" shortcuts and some more, so there would be a conflict. BTW, your remark about Tab-Tab was very useful, because I didn't know this trick :) Did you try all the shortcuts in the "unofficial" version or only the official ones?

Comment: In the meantime I understand what you mean by using both without conflicts. Actually I like the "unofficial" Tab behavior better, because it has an Edit/Object toggle, which is actually closer to the old Tab.

Answer (score 6):

The official one, made by Sebastian Koeing, comes with Blender automatically. I think you might have installed the first one manually, since I don't have it.

You could use the first one if you like. Whichever one fits you.

Comment: Thank you, I upvoted the answer, but I won't accept it yet. I hope someone has a deeper answer than "Whichever one fits you." - I don't feel like spending a lot of time comparing them.

Comment: @WannaKnow - If you don't "feel like comparing" them for yourself and let s.o. other decide what's best for you, you might as well throw a coin. Blender's UI and its possibility to extend it is all about personal preferences.

Comment: @metaphor_set I also don't want to throw coins :) I wanna know. Maybe one version is not well tested, but in some way it is better. I am looking for concrete information, not for generic advice.